# Inefficient Binary Search Tree Balanced Algorithm

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am working on a project with Binary Search trees. This project requires me to create a method called isBalanced that checks if a binary search tree is balanced within a tolerance. I was able to figure out how to do this but it is dreadfully slow. I was wondering if anyone had any tips to make it more efficient. By the way, .getLeftChild() and .getRightChild() have to return IllegalStateExceptions if the child is null. I would much prefer them to return null personally.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
@Override
public <T> int getDepth(BinaryTreeNode<T> root) {
    return recDepth(root,0);
}

public <T> int recDepth(BinaryTreeNode<T> root,int depth) {
    int leftTree,rightTree;
    if(!root.hasLeftChild()&&!root.hasRightChild()) return depth;

    if(!root.hasLeftChild()) leftTree = 0;
    else                     leftTree = recDepth(root.getLeftChild(),depth+1);

    if(!root.hasRightChild()) rightTree = 0;
    else                      rightTree = recDepth(root.getRightChild(),depth+1);

    if(rightTree>leftTree) return rightTree; 
    else                   return leftTree;
}

@Override
public <T> boolean isBalanced(BinaryTreeNode<T> root, int tolerance) {
    if(tolerance<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't have negative tolerance");
    if(root==null) throw new NullPointerException();
    return recBalanced(root,tolerance);
}

public <T> boolean recBalanced(BinaryTreeNode<T> root, int tolerance){
    try{
    if(Math.abs(getDepth(root.getLeftChild())-getDepth(root.getLeftChild()))<=tolerance){
        return recBalanced(root.getLeftChild(),tolerance)&&recBalanced(root.getRightChild(),tolerance);
    }else return false;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        if(root.hasLeftChild()&&getDepth(root.getLeftChild())>tolerance-1) return false;
        else if(root.hasRightChild()&&getDepth(root.getRightChild())>tolerance-1) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I reformatted the code to make it more readable, but you could improve it using the conditional operator (I didn't do it because I don't wanted to denaturate the code)

Comment: Sorry it wasn't very readable, thanks for editing.

Comment: That's why it was a comment and not an answer. I have indentified th reason of the efficiency of this code and trying to propose you a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of efficiency comes from the fact that you are traversing the same elements several times to compute the depth of a subtree and then the depth of its right and left subtrees.

When you have such overlapping problems that can be deduced by smaller problems, a bell must ring in your head : **dynamic programming**. You can compute a `BinaryTreeNode<Integer>`, that would contain the depth of each corresponding node (this tree would have the same shape as the original tree). You would then only need to traverse this tree once to perform your computation, for a total time complexity of `O(n)` (a memory used of `O(n)` however).

```
public BinaryTreeNode<Integer> computeDepthTree(BinaryTreeNode<T> bt) {
    return computeDepth(bt,0);
}

public BinaryTreeNode<Integer> computeDepthTree(BinaryTreeNode<T> bt, int depth) {
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> result = new BinaryTreeNode<>(depth);
    if (bt.getLeftNode() != null)
        result.setLeftNode(computeDepthTree(bt.getLeftNode(),depth + 1));

    if (bt.getRightNode() != null)
        result.setRightNode(computeDepthTree(bt.getRightNode(),depth + 1));

    return result;
}
```

With this tree computed, when traversing a given node, you will get access to its depth in `O(1)` so the comparison of depth between child nodes of a same parent is going to be cheap !

Comment: I am sorry if I sound completely inexperienced but I am not sure how I would do that. Also, did you mean O(1) time complexity?

Comment: No it is a `O(n)` because all the nodes are traversed once or twice.

Comment: I understand now, sorry I just got confused since you said however. Your solution is brilliant. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your method is the inverse of what I wanted but with your idea coding that was trivial.

Comment: Ok, happy to know it helped you. I would not be against a kind upvote though :)

Comment: I would if I could. I need 15 reputation sorry!